# constructing a specific (real-) analytic function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples

Im searching for an example of a special-behaving analytic function. Maybe you can beat me to constructing such one. The criterias are

- $g :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ is analytic
- $g$ is $\mathcal{L}^1$ (implicitly $\liminf_{x\rightarrow \infty}xg(x)=0$)
- $\limsup_{x\rightarrow \infty} xg(x)>0$

If you can give an example with a easy expression for the antiderivative, double the love is awarded

Comment: Don't you mean $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of $|x|g(x)$?

Comment: Your criteria implies mine. Im only interested in restrictions for $x>0$.

Comment: $g(x) = \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2 (x-n)^2}$

Comment: can you prove it is analytic ?

Comment: Edit: ohhohh. limits of analytic functions are only analytic in the complex case

Comment: is it $L^1$ ? (I meant $g(x) = \sum_n e^{-n^4 (x-n)^2}$)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42910/discussion-between-conformal-and-user1952009).

Comment: @user1952009 : And I suppose you need to remove the $n=0$ case from the sum.

Comment: @Michael good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a solution is $$g(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty, n \ne 0}^\infty e^{-n^4 (x-n)^2}$$

- it is real analytic since it is complex analytic
- it is $L^1$ since $$\|g\|_{L^1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^4 (x-n)^2} dx =  \sum_{n=-\infty, n \ne 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = 2\frac{\pi^2}{6}\sqrt{2\pi}$$
- and clearly $g(x) \ge 0$ and $\displaystyle\underset{|x| \to \infty}{\lim \sup} g(x) = 1$

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. The idea i needed was that uniform limits of (complex extended) analytic functions are analytic.

Comment: Looks like batman.

Answer (score 0):

The function

$$f(x) = \left ( \frac{2+\cos x}{3} \right) ^{x^4}$$

has this property. This follows from the fact that $\int_0^{2\pi} [(2+\cos x)/3]^n\, dx \sim 1/\sqrt n$ as $n\to \infty$ (by Laplace's method).